# Prove Laplace equality ${\cal L}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s-\alpha}-\sqrt{s-\beta}\right)=\frac{1}{2t\sqrt{\pi t}}[e^{(\beta t)} - e^{(\alpha t)}]$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, gamma-function

I have to prove the Laplace transform equality

> $${\cal L}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s-\alpha}-\sqrt{s-\beta}\right)=\frac{1}{2t\sqrt{\pi t}}[e^{(\beta t)} - e^{(\alpha t)}]$$

Help.

Comment: You should add some details about what you have done so far, and what your ideas are to compute the laplace transform.

Comment: A Laplace transform ($\mathcal{L}$) is actually missing in your equality. As written, it is not an equality.

Answer (score 0):

With $\displaystyle\Gamma(\frac12)=\sqrt{\pi}$, $\Gamma(p+1)=p\Gamma(p)$ and
$$\color{blue}{{\cal L}(t^p)=\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{s^{p+1}}}$$
write
$${\cal L}\left(\frac{1}{t\sqrt{t}}\right)={\cal L}(t^\frac{-3}{2})=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{-3}{2}+1)}{s^{\frac{-3}{2}+1}}=\Gamma(\frac{-1}{2})\sqrt{s}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\frac{-1}{2}}\sqrt{s}=-2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{s}$$
and by shifting property
$$\color{blue}{{\cal L}(e^{ct}f(t))=F(s-c)}$$
so
$${\cal L}\left(e^{\alpha t}\frac{1}{t\sqrt{t}}\right)=-2\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{s-\alpha}$$